# SwiftUI Picker problem after dismissing .fullScreenCover or .sheet

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a picker that works fine until after showing and dismissing a fullScreenCover or a sheet. Does anyone know what the problem is with this sample code, or have a work-around?

I have tried dismissing the sheet using self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss() as well, but with the same result.

Example gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmcmv.gif

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedFilterStatus = ActiveStatus.active
    @State var showDetail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    showDetail.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Detail popup")
                })
                
                Picker("\(selectedFilterStatus.title)", selection: $selectedFilterStatus) {
                    Text(ActiveStatus.active.title).tag(ActiveStatus.active)
                    Text(ActiveStatus.inactive.title).tag(ActiveStatus.inactive)
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDetail, content: {
                MyDetailsView(presenting: $showDetail)
            })
        }
        .navigationTitle("Main")
    }
}

struct MyDetailsView: View {
    @Binding var presenting: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello from details!")
            Button(action: {
                presenting.toggle()
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    Text("Back")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

enum ActiveStatus: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case active
    case inactive
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

extension ActiveStatus {
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .active:
            return "Active for sale"
        case .inactive:
            return "Inactive"
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure looks like a SwiftUI bug to me. Have you filed a Feedback with Apple?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue as well. I also played with the code a bit and found that using a `ForEach` in the `Picker` exhibits the same behavior. Also that if you DO NOT make a picker selection before navigating to the detail, then it works properly. It is only AFTER making a picker selection and then navigating that the picker fails. Please post your Radar # when you file this one.

Comment: @jnpdx Yes, I agree. It looks like a bug. I have not filed it with Apple yet. I was hoping maybe someone knew a work around...

Comment: @Yrb, I noticed the same, but I fail to understand why...

Comment: The consensus is this is a bug. Don't try to understand it as to why it is doing what it is doing. Just file the report, and post the number so we can reference it. You found it, you get first dibs.

Comment: I filed a report through the Feedback Assistant. ID: FB9721693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree there is a bug in the system. However, you can get around it.
This is the workaround that works for me, tested on ios-15 and macCatalyst (macos12.01) devices:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedFilterStatus = ActiveStatus.active
    @State var showDetail: ActiveStatus? // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    showDetail = ActiveStatus.active  // <-- here
                }, label: { Text("Detail popup") })
                
                Picker("\(selectedFilterStatus.title)", selection: $selectedFilterStatus) {
                    Text(ActiveStatus.active.title).tag(ActiveStatus.active)
                    Text(ActiveStatus.inactive.title).tag(ActiveStatus.inactive)
                }.pickerStyle(.menu)
                
            }
            // -- here --
            .fullScreenCover(item: $showDetail) { _ in
                MyDetailsView()
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .navigationTitle("Main")
    }
}

struct MyDetailsView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello from details!")
            Button(action: {
                dismiss()  // <-- here
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    Text("Back")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

enum ActiveStatus: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case active
    case inactive
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

extension ActiveStatus {
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .active:
            return "Active for sale"
        case .inactive:
            return "Inactive"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @workingdog! That works :) I'm not sure I understand why though, is it because using showDetail in this way forces the view to refresh?

Comment: I don't understand why it works either. Maybe the bug is in the other "version" of `fullScreenCover` and not in this one.